# What is the correct function callback syntax?

Tags: javascript, callback

In javascript, how do I write the call to a function, with a callback, when the function has at least one parameter?

When using callbacks, the following is what I understand:

```
var result = foo();
```

becomes

```
foo(function(result) {
    // code that depends on 'result'
});
```

However, if `foo` takes a parameter, how should the call to `foo` be written?

Is it something along the lines of the following:

```
var result = foo(testdata);
```

becomes

```
foo(function(result), testdata {
    // code that depends on 'result'
});
```

or

```
foo(function(result, testdata){
    // code that depends on 'result'
});
```

I am not sure on the correct syntax. Can someone please point me to a resource or help me with the correct syntax?

Comment: `function (a,b,c,..) { }` <- *that* is the callback. The parameters that are supplied (as well as the `this` context) to the *callback* depends on who calls it. Additional parameters to the *(non-callback) function* and order depend on the API. In both these cases 'rtfm'.

Comment: Please note that this has nothing to do with jQuery whatsoever. I recommend to read a tutorial about functions, for example http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html

Comment: What is expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass them as 2 different parameters like

```
foo(testdata, function(result){
   //do things with result
});
```

then foo is defined as

```
function foo(testdata, callback){
    //call callback when result is ready
}
```